# jekyll for loop don't show post's title

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I have some post in `_post` directory and I need to show in the browser in two columns using `Bootstrap` (and using `Jekyll`).This is my code:

```
{% capture cant_element %}{{ site.posts.size | divided_by:2 }}{% endcapture %}
{% for i in (0..cant_element) %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {% capture new_i %}{{ i | times:2 }}{% endcapture %}
    {{ new_i }}
    {{ site.posts[new_i].title }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {% capture new_i_plus %}{{ i | times:2 | plus:1 }}{% endcapture %}
    {{ new_i_plus }}
    {{ site.posts[new_i_plus].title }}
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I cant see (in the browser) the variables `new_i` and `new_i_plus` but don't show the post titles (`site.posts[new_i_plus].title`)

Why? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You are confounding `capture` and `assign` tags.

Any `{% capture %}any code here{% endcapture %}` returns a string.

So when you try to get an element by his index number, like `{{ site.posts[new_i].title }}` where `new_i` is a string, it's like doing `{{ site.posts['0'].title }}`, and it returns nothing because the `'0'` string is not an index.

Doing an assignment like `{% assign new_i = i | times:2 %}` will return a `Fixnum` (a number). Your `{{ site.posts[new_i].title }}` will now translate to `{{ site.posts[0].title }}` and will return something because `new_i` is a number and a real index.

#### your logic will not loop over all posts (sometimes)

`{{ site.posts.size | divided_by:2 }}` will return an absolute value. If you have 3 posts this will return 1, and your loop will always neglect the last post with an odd index.

#### An other way to get things done

Using [liquid iteration tags](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags) you can do it more efficiently.

```
{% for p in site.posts %}
    {% assign isEven = forloop.index0 | modulo: 2 %}
    {% if isEven == 0 %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>{{ site.posts[forloop.index0].title }}</h2>
            </div>
            {% if forloop.rindex0 > 0 %}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>{{ site.posts[forloop.index].title }}</h2>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {% continue %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```